# Disable activeform action and method in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

How can i disable the form method and action automaticaly created by yii2 active form?

```
<div class="well">
              <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                'action' => [''],'options' => ['method' => '']
                ]); ?>
              <?= $form->field($model, 'Title')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style'=>'width:300px']) ?>

              <?= Html::button('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary leavetype-save', 'value'=>'save']) ?>
           </div>
           <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

          </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "disable"? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: i just want to remove the action and the method in the form which is automatically created when active form is used.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible via parameters. You will need to override `yii\widgets\ActiveForm` (particularly the [`run()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/9a16f8fecc21e72173b1633075bd45048ad0c3aa/framework/widgets/ActiveForm.php#L205) method) and manually render the form without the `action` and `method` options.

Comment: i just override the action by 'action' => '#', this but not with the method

Comment: Yes, that's not going to work. Like I said, you need to override the actual method in ActiveForm (AKA create your own ActiveForm class).